# Account auto-logoff after sysprep

Tags: windows-7

I recently transferred my OS (Win7_x64) to a new computer. Everything works so far, but when I log on with my old account, it immediately logs off. On the old computer, I did not have this issue.

What could be the reason for it? In the event log I can see it's initiating logon & logoff, but no errors.
I disabled all startup items I could find. So it shouldn't be a program.
And in safe mode, I can log into the account no problem (but my taskbar is different then it was on my original computer?? - I thought sysprep took everything with it?).

Thanks for anyone who can help me with this here!

Edit: The only thing I have in the event viewer is this:

```
Information 2/05/2015 13:09:08  User Profile Service    4   None
Information 2/05/2015 13:09:08  User Profile Service    3   None
Information 2/05/2015 13:09:07  GroupPolicy 5311    None
Information 2/05/2015 13:09:07  User Profile Service    2   None
Information 2/05/2015 13:09:06  User Profile Service    1   None
```

Or more detailed:

```
Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-User Profile Service/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service
Date:          2/05/2015 13:09:08
Event ID:      4
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      
User:          STEVEN-PC\Steven
Computer:      Steven-PC
Description:
Finished processing user logoff notification on session 1.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service" Guid="{89B1E9F0-5AFF-44A6-9B44-0A07A7CE5845}" />
    <EventID>4</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-05-02T11:09:08.604820200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>300</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="1556" ThreadID="4908" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-User Profile Service/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>Steven-PC</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1550641888-1495511497-3287687050-1000" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="Session">1</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-User Profile Service/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service
Date:          2/05/2015 13:09:08
Event ID:      3
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      
User:          STEVEN-PC\Steven
Computer:      Steven-PC
Description:
Recieved user logoff notification on session 1.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service" Guid="{89B1E9F0-5AFF-44A6-9B44-0A07A7CE5845}" />
    <EventID>3</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-05-02T11:09:08.272206300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>299</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="1556" ThreadID="4908" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-User Profile Service/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>Steven-PC</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1550641888-1495511497-3287687050-1000" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="Session">1</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy
Date:          2/05/2015 13:09:07
Event ID:      5311
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      
User:          STEVEN-PC\Steven
Computer:      Steven-PC
Description:
The loopback policy processing mode is "No loopback mode".
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy" Guid="{AEA1B4FA-97D1-45F2-A64C-4D69FFFD92C9}" />
    <EventID>5311</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-05-02T11:09:07.103954200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1198</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{4A74AD3B-30E3-44D7-867A-C012659BBC1D}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="1672" ThreadID="5492" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>Steven-PC</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1550641888-1495511497-3287687050-1000" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="PolicyProcessingMode">0</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-User Profile Service/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service
Date:          2/05/2015 13:09:07
Event ID:      2
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      
User:          STEVEN-PC\Steven
Computer:      Steven-PC
Description:
Finished processing user logon notification on session 1.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service" Guid="{89B1E9F0-5AFF-44A6-9B44-0A07A7CE5845}" />
    <EventID>2</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-05-02T11:09:07.101954100Z" />
    <EventRecordID>298</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="1556" ThreadID="4172" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-User Profile Service/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>Steven-PC</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1550641888-1495511497-3287687050-1000" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="Session">1</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-User Profile Service/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service
Date:          2/05/2015 13:09:06
Event ID:      1
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      
User:          STEVEN-PC\Steven
Computer:      Steven-PC
Description:
Recieved user logon notification on session 1.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service" Guid="{89B1E9F0-5AFF-44A6-9B44-0A07A7CE5845}" />
    <EventID>1</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-05-02T11:09:06.968748200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>296</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="1556" ThreadID="4172" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-User Profile Service/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>Steven-PC</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1550641888-1495511497-3287687050-1000" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="Session">1</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I just tried via msconfig to disable ALL (non-Microsoft) services, and ALL Startup items. I still can login to the newly created "Test" account, not to "Steven".

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was that HKEY_USERS\S-... was owned by some weird account. Reverting it to my own solved the problem. (Edit -> Permissions -> Add my account & give it full control over the right sub-key).

But remember to replace the keys recursively!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. This is happening because when you transferred your system, the environment changed, but the environment variables in Win7 didn't.

Boot into safe mode and update them. (you can find more help on the internet)

Comment: I don't think this would be it... I have 3 in there: MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH, which is empty. And TMP (and TEMP) which is %USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Temp. Which resolves fine. The others are system variables, which cannot cause the issue in my opinion as I can log on with my new created "Test" account just fine. (Besides, they all look fine to point to correct dirs.). Is there any way I can debug the logon process?

Comment: I still think the problem is there. Windows creates new variables with new accounts (even system variables). Can you post them here?

Comment: I think I'm getting there. The registry keys under HKEY_USERS were owned by an "Unknown account". So I'm fixing this, and trying to figure out where this link is laid.